# In C ---[Error] cannot convert 'char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument '1' to 'int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)'

Tags: c, pointers

Hello friends I want to read a srt file then a signed number (in milliseconds) as its inputs and add/subtract that amount of time from all of the content of the file and store the modified file.I am a very beginner of C language.I try something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME_SIZE 1024

struct Response{
    char responseBody[25];
};
int main(){
    struct Response fileError{"Error openning file.\n"
    };
    struct Response fileSuccess{"File found!!"
    };
    FILE *file;
    FILE *newfile;
    int hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds;
    
    char filename[FILENAME_SIZE];
    
    printf("File:");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    file = fopen(filename,"r");
    
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("%s",fileError.responseBody);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s",fileSuccess.responseBody);
    
    int cnt;
    
    printf("enter a number for adding");
    scanf("%d",cnt);
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)!=NULL){
        if(sscanf(line, "%*d:%*d:%*d,%*d --> %*d:%*d:%*d,%*d", NULL) == 0){
            continue;
        }
        newfile=fopen("updatedfile.srt","w");
        scanf(line, "%d:%d:%d,%d", &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &milliseconds);
        milliseconds += cnt;
        if (milliseconds < 0) {
            seconds--;
            milliseconds += 1000;
        }
        else if (milliseconds > 999) {
            seconds++;
            milliseconds -= 1000;
        }
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds += 60;
        }       
        else if (seconds > 59) {
            minutes++;
            seconds -= 60;
        }
        if (minutes < 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes += 60;
        }   
        else if (minutes > 59) {
        hours++;
        minutes -= 60;
        }
        fprintf(line, "%02d:%02d:%02d,%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
        fclose(newfile);
    }
}
```

But this error occurs :

> [Error] cannot convert 'char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument
> '1' to 'int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)'

I understand 1st parameter is wrong but I dont know how to fix actually.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: When you know ```fprintf``` expects a ```FILE *```, why did you pass it a ```char *```?

Comment: You just scanned your `line` variable to get your data.  Why are you trying to print back to it?  I'm guessing you want `newfile` there, not `line`.  Isn't it `newfile` (that is, updatedfile.srt) that you want to print the entered data to?

Comment: Your `sscanf` has UB (undefined behavior) and will segfault because you're passing `NULL` for something that should be an `int *` and have non-existent/undefined values for the other _necessary_ arguments in the `sscanf` call. And, then, you're calling `scanf` to get the real data. Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` is _problematic_. It would help if you edited your question and posted some sample input in a separate code block.

Comment: I cant explain my problem very well.Let me explain,I have a srt file and I want to add/substract that amount of time from all the content of my srt file then store all of them in modified file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number problems here.

- `fprintf` takes a `FILE *` as its first argument, specifying the file to write to.  You're passing `line` (a `char` buffer used for input), which makes no sense -- you probably meant `newfile`, the file you're trying to create
- you call `fopen`/`fclose` of your output file *inside* the loop -- meaning you reopen (and replace the old contents) on each iteration, so you'll end up with just the last line output in the file.  You need to open the file before the start of the loop and close it after the loop completes (*outside* the loop) in order to get all the output lines in it.
- your `sscanf` call will always return 0 (and thus skip the rest of the loop) as all of the patterns in the format are suppressed.  If you want to skip lines that match all of that pattern, you want something like:

  ```
    int end = -1;
    if (sscanf(line, "%*d:%*d:%*d,%*d --> %*d:%*d:%*d,%*d%n", &end), end > 0)
        continue;
  ```
- your `scanf` call should be `sscanf`, and you should check that it returns `4` before trying to use those values (give an error message and skip the line if it doesn't?)
- if the user enters a `cnt` bigger that 1000 (or less than -1000), you'll get out-of-range millisecond values in your output.  You should probably check for that and either give the user an error message or deal with it (split cnt into cnt_milli, cnt_seconds, cnt_min, etc)

  ```
    cnt_milli = cnt % 1000;
    cnt_sec = (cnt/1000) % 60;
    cnt_min = (cnt/60000) % 60;
    cnt_hour = (cnt/3600000);
  ```